# Android matrix postscale with aniamtion

Tags: android, matrix, android-imageview

A think a do not understand enough matrices theory to build animation for matrix inside image view. 
For example i have some value that i want to set in postScale method to my matrix.

I use this code

```
fun animateScale(scale_factor:Float,matrix: Matrix)
{
    matrix.postScale(scale_factor,scale_factor)
    image_view.imageMatrix = matrix
}
```

This code makes scale to image view as it is expected. But i cant calculate postScale with animation. I tried different approaches using `ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f)` or `ValueAnimator.ifInt(1, 100)` but result is weird.

Updated 
I added my tries of animating as it asked in comments.

```
val animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f)
    animator.addUpdateListener(
        { animation ->

            val current_anim_value = animation.animatedValue as Float

            val factor_to_anim = scale_factor - ( scale_factor * current_anim_value)
            matrix.postScale(factor_to_anim, factor_to_anim)
            image_view.imageMatrix = matrix
        })

    animator.duration = 3000
    animator.start()
```

Comment: Weird how? What happens?

Comment: In short, it flies out of screen.

Comment: Can you post the code you use for animation, the one using `ValueAnimator`.

Comment: Nicolas, i have updated my question.

Comment: What animation are you trying to achieve? Just a linear scale up?

Comment: postScale. It is matrix transformation. This question is more about matrices in 2d graphics. It seems like you cant understand my question because you focused on common android animation.

Comment: postScale just post concatenates a scale matrix to the original matrix. But it also scales the translation components, which might be why you're seeing the image flying out of the screen. Also, I doubt the validity of the incremental scale transformations you're doing, partly because I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, which is why I asked what kind of animation you want.

Comment: I have a matrix, and i have a scale factor that i need to apply to it. With no animation this works as it should. But with using animation i need some how divide this scale factor by each animation update value so that after all updates sum of all applied animation would be this scale factor.

Comment: I suggest you make a copy of the original matrix, then apply a different scale factor on it every time the animation is updated. This way you don't need to make successive transformations.

Comment: I tried this approach with using setScale instead of postScale. It does not work if used with some other transformation, in my case it is transform. So the only solution is calculating postScale values in animation updateListener.